# Get Wine path of file

Tags: filepath, wine

Is it possible to get the Wine path to a file on the current OS?

Example:

```
wine-get-path ~/foo.txt # Outputs: Z:\\Users\Tyilo\foo.txt
wine-get-path ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/explorer.exe # Output: C:\\windows\\explorer.exe
```

where `wine-get-path` would be the function I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is `winepath -w foofile`