# Detecting Unix home in Wine application

Tags: unix, wine, home-directory

My Windows application is frequently used on *nix using Wine.

As it is a file-centric application, it frequently uses (and presents to an user) Windows "documents" folder (as resolved using `CSIDL_PERSONAL`). Unfortunately under Wine that points to fake Wine/Windows directory that's usually empty and unused. I'd like to point user to his Unix home folder instead.

Is there any reliable way to find out its location under Wine?

I was hoping I can read `HOME` environment variable, but it's not exported (contrary to most other variables) to Windows environment.

Currently I'm guessing the home using `Z:\home\%USERNAME%`. But that does not look robust to me.

If there's no way to find home directory, is there at least a way to detect Wine root drive (`Z:` by default), so I do not need to hard-code at least a drive-part of path?

Comment: I think this belongs in superuser or linux.

Comment: I never tried, but I would try at least SHGetFolderPath with CSIDL_PROFILE.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways I'm pretty sure I cannot detect it from environment (or other power-user-level interface). So I'm hoping for some API. As such it belongs here, afaik.

Comment: does any of this help? http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/environment-variables

Comment: @Martin: CSIDL_PROFILE != CSIDL_PERSONAL. The "My Documents" folder has no standardized Unix equivalent, but the profile directory on Unix is ~. Maybe it returns some fake directory anyway, but I would give it a try (another possibility is that it returns a "strange" directory that is actually a symlink to the home).

Comment: @PressingOnAlways I've seen this before. Though not sure how this helps. It made me believe that `HOME` is propagated (not being on black list like `PATH`, `SYSTEM` and `TEMP`). But it's not.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl is other variables propagated? If so, can you just do export CUSTOM_HOME = $HOME or something like this in a bash script before you launch wine?

Comment: @PressingOnAlways Yes of course. That's a hack I'm using atm, but I'd like my application to work on it's own, without need for Wine-specific wrapping script

Comment: @MatteoItalia Sorry, I didn't notice you refer to different `CSIDL*`. But as expected `CSIDL_PROFILE` refers to `C:\users\%USERNAME%`.

Comment: I have a few games installed in different directories, and all of them have $WINE_PREFIX/drive_c/windows/profiles/<username>/{Desktop,Documents,Music,...} a symlink to those in my $HOME (while the "All Users" directories are fake). Do you see anything different?

Comment: @loreb That's true. But the "My Documents" link is hidden on WinAPI level for some reason. ("My Music", "Desktop" and others are not). By hidden I mean absent (not hidden attribute). What makes it even worse actually as when `CSIDL_PERSONAL` resolves to kind-of non-existing folder, applications do not behave nicely. Even native Wine "Windows Explorer" gets confused, when you manually type in "My Documents" path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a lack of better answer, I'm sharing my current workaround/hack:

For *nix platforms, where I have deployment under control (OS X particularly), I copy the `HOME` environment variable to another variable from a startup script (say the `WINE_HOME`). Most environment variables (with notable exception of the `HOME`) are exported to Windows/Wine environment. So I can read the `WINE_HOME` from my application, prepend `Z:\` and convert slashes to backslashes.

For platforms, where I do not have deployment under control, I can use the `USERNAME` variable only to guess the home as `Z:\home\%USERNAME%`. This particularly does not work on OS X, where the home is in the `/users` not the `/home`.

EDIT: I found a question [Get Wine path of file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7204313/850848) that helps a bit. In *nix you can use the `winepath -w ~` to get `Z:\home\username`. But running the same from Windows environment does not resolve the `~`. You can at least run the `winepath -w /home/username` to get `Z:\home\username` to find out a drive of the Wine root (in case it's not the default `Z:\`).

Answer (score 2):

In Wine drive `Z:` always maps to the root (`/`) hence your way of detecting is cool. But if the user does

`rm ~/.wine/dosdevices/z\:`

this won't work of course. In wine mailing this there was a [discussion](http://marc.info/?l=wine-devel&m=115366499402354&w=2) about the security implications of `Z:` mapping.

Comment: You can actually map `/` to any drive you want using `winecfg`. See https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Drive_Settings *(comment re-posted with an updated link - originally posted in April 2014)*